# Concise and accurate printing of doubles

Tags: c++, printf

I have a `double x` which I'd like to print as a string `s`. I'd like the representation to obey the following properties:

- **Accurate**: the absolute value of `(x - atof(s))` is less than epsilon
- **Concise**: the representation doesn't include more significant digits than required to be accurate

What is the best way to do this?

To illustrate why `%f` and `%g` don't do the job:

```
printf("%f\n", 1.0);              // 1.000000       not concise
printf("%g\n", 1.0);              // 1              good
printf("%f\n", 4357890.2342389);  // 4357890.234239 good
printf("%g\n", 4357890.2342389);  // 4.35789e+06    not accurate
```

Comment: `%.16g` or something similar?

Comment: @cpplearner Cool, that works great. If you submit as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Although `%.16g` works well for my above examples, it technically fails my "concise" definition for something like `1.0/3` if epsilon is, say, 1e-6. The solution is good for my needs, but I want to note this in case others have different requirements.

Comment: What's your expected output for "`1.0/3` if epsilon is, say, 1e-6"? 0.333333?

Comment: @Bob__ Yes. No other string satisfies my requirements, technically.

Comment: So you only need to modify the precision in the posted answers to your needs: `std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << 1.0/3 << '\n';`

Comment: Yeah but then that fails on 10.0/3.

Comment: Try `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6) << 10.0/3 << '\n';`

Comment: @Bob__ That works. But then, both fail on 1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use as ([cpplearner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4672588/cpplearner) mentioned) format specifier `%.16g` for printf or do it with `std::cout` and [std::setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) like so :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << 4357890.2342389 << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::setprecision(16);

    std::cout << 4357890.2342389 << std::endl;
    std::cout << 1.0 << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::fixed;
    std::cout << "fixed\n";

    std::cout << 4357890.2342389 << std::endl;
}
```

which produces:

```
4.35789e+06
4357890.2342389
1
fixed
4357890.2342389002442360
```

Online code [link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MvrvmKYeN9RVolGj)

Note: that you always have to take into consideration floating point precision problems.

Recommended reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: As I note in a comment on the OP, this solution works well for my needs, but technically fails my "concise" definition for something like `1.0/3` if epsilon is, say, 1e-6. Making note of this in case someone actually desires the requirements I precisely laid out in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

To meet your requirements you can do something as ugly as this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string concise_and_accurate( double x, int prec ) {
    // print the number to a stringstream with all the figures needed
    std::stringstream strnum;
    strnum << std::fixed << std::setprecision(prec) << x;
    std::string str = strnum.str();
    // cancel the extra zeroes at the right
    str.erase( str.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, std::string::npos );
    // delete the '.' if there are no other digits at the right
    if ( str[str.size()-1] == '.' ) str.erase(str.size()-1);
    return str; 
}


int main() {
    double test[] = { 4357890.2342389, 1.0, 1.0/3, 100.0/3 };

    for ( auto x : test ) {
        std::cout << concise_and_accurate(x,6) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
4357890.234239
1
0.333333
33.333333
```

Comment: A heroic effort! Our system actually uses printf-style formatting, with the string conversions done in a separate low-priority thread, for performance reasons. I might eventually adopt your solution, using custom % formatters, but first I'll need to solve [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334179/custom-support-for-attribute-format), which has been on our TODO list for awhile.

Comment: @dshin I always thought that the whole point of `<iostream>` was to get rid of all the % formatters and provide a type safe buffered IO. But it came at a cost, of course. Have you measured the difference in performance of the two methods trying to minimizing the write calls (few cout with big concatenated strings)?

Comment: Yes, cout is simply too slow for our performance requirements. Out-of-the-box printf would also be too slow, since the cost of `printf("a really long format string %d\n", 10)` scales with the length of the format string. Our system just copies the format string address along with the arguments to a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can configure the format specifier like explained here:

[Format specifiers in C](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Since you are tagging this as C++ why not try this out:

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << double(1.0) << std::endl
std::cout << 1.0 << std::endl
std::cout << double(4357890.2342389) << std::endl    
std::cout << 4357890.2342389 << std::endl
```

if you want more precision you can

```
std::cout << std::setw(32) << std::setprecision(16) << double(1.0);
```

why leads to print out more characters of your number.

Comment: What's the reason for casting double values to type double?

Comment: Does `iostream` produce better results than `printf`? If yes, which aspects are improved - is it more accurate? More concise? Both?

Comment: It is the C++ way to the those things. The result should be about the same, but you don't have to provide format specifiers. If you change your data type no updates of the format specifier is requiered in your stream calls.

Comment: C++'s formatting for floating-point is abysmal. Unless you specify fixed/scientific/whatever, you are completely at its whims.

Comment: With double cast you force the number to store as double and pass the stream. Just wanted to show it is another option.